# parsing string into UTC time

Tags: jodatime

In the following example, I imagined that startTime will be interpreted, as a time in UTC(because i put Z in startTime). But parseDateTime, parses it into local timeZOne. How do i make "parseDateTime" think that startTime is in UTC(using the format below)??

```
val format = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"
val formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(format)

val startTime = "2014-11-25T08:40:00.611Z"

val startTimeObj = formatter.parseDateTime(startTime)
println("startTimeObj : " + startTimeObj)
```

> startTimeObj : 2014-11-25T08:40:00.611-08:00

Comment: Looks like you are printing the `DateTime` object (with its built in `.toString()` representation) - `DateTime` objects do not have a 'format` (they are just dates) - if you want to print out a date on a specific format, you use the formatter (like you did on the first two lines)

Comment: @ochi: when i look in the debugger to see what value startTimeObj holds, it contains 2014-11-25T08:40:00.611-08:00.  SO my question is having Z in the startTime does not really say to the parser that the time is in UTC?

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern says `'Z'` which is just a literal 'Z' character rather than being interpreted as a timezone. Just take the quotes off and so that your pattern says `.SSSZ`

Of course, for this format you could simply use DateTime.parse()